# however before an adjective

Tags: grammar, syntax, parts-of-speech

What is the part of speech of the 'experienced' in the following text? Can you please explain the grammatical structure of the sentence that contains this word?

> Market research is a vital part of the planning of any business.
>   However **experienced** you or your staff may be in a particular field, if
>   you are thinking of introducing a service to a new area, it is
>   important to find out what the local population thinks about it first.

Comment: I think it's a fronted complement. *"You or your staff may be experienced in.. "*.

Comment: Native English speakers do not say *may you...?* to make a request. Use *could you...?* (or *would you...?*; or even *will you...?*; note *might you...?* is possible but rare. But never *may you...?*)

Comment: *however* means *no matter how* here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"However experienced you or your staff may be in a particular field" is equal to "No matter how experienced you or your staff may be in a particular field", meaning you or your staff should not have too much confidence in your experience or knowledge. "experienced" is used as an adjective here.

Quoting the definition of "[however](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/however)" from Collins English Dictionary:

> You use however before an adjective or adverb to emphasize that the degree or extent of something cannot change a situation.
>   Example: *You should always strive to achieve more, however well you have done before.*